# Matrix algebras are a tensor products?

Tags: tensor-products

I am working with $M_{k\times k}[M_{n\times n}[\mathbb{C}]]$ which is $k\times k$ matrices with entries from the vector space of $n\times n$ matrices with complex entries. I was told that this is obviously $M_{k\times k}[\mathbb{C}]\otimes M_{n\times n}[\mathbb{C}]$ when $k, n$ are finite. I don't know much representation theory or about matrix algebra, is it possible to get some pointers about why this is, or isn't, true?

Comment: We have in general $M_k(R \otimes S) \cong M_k(R) \otimes S$. But it's easier to describe $M_k(M_n(\mathbb{C}))$ as just $M_{kn}(\mathbb{C})$.

Comment: Ah, so the idea is that since $\otimes$ is over $\mathbb C$ , $M_n(M_k(\mathbb C ))) = M_n(\mathbb C \otimes M_k(\mathbb C ))) = M_n(\mathbb C) \otimes M_k(\mathbb C)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may show this equality in an elementary way using the Kronecker product of matrices of the canonical basis $(E_{ij}^{(k)})$ of $M_k(\mathbb C)$ and 
$ (E^{(n)}_{st})$ of $M_n(\mathbb C)$.
 In fact,
$$
E_{ij}^{(k)}\otimes E^{(n)}_{st} = E^{(kn)}_{(i-1)n + s, (j-1)n + t}
$$ 
The matrices $\{E^{kn}_{(i-1)n + s, (j-1)n + t}\}$ form the canonical basis of $M_{kn}(\mathbb C)$.  $\square$